# Continuous Looping through sheets and macro to stop the action

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie vba user..
The title might be slightly misleading but essentially I am starting with Sheet 1,2,3 and 4.

I would need to create a macro to cycle through the spreadsheets, kind of like a powerpoint presentation with a 10 seconds interval.

I tried to google and search the web, however only able to find this

Sub DisplayLoop()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True  its true by default

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

wkb.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

wkb.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
End Sub
```

I need help to make it endless continuous to loop around from sheet 1 - 3 and a macro to stop the continuous looping..

Hope they are kind souls out there to assist me.
Thank you so much..

**EDIT**: finally able to modify the code to this.. it repeats for x times.
**EDIT** Is there a way to PAUSE the running macro? How do I modify the code?

```
 Sub DisplayLoop()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True  its true by default

Dim I
For I = 1 To 20

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

wkb.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

wkb.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to loop through ALL sheets in book or several of them?

Comment: Hi Taosique, I only need to loop only sheet 1,2 and 3. I managed to modify my code. Refer to my edit. Now I would need to create another module to stop the macro.  Is it possible to I = 1 to (infinite?)

Answer (score 0):

Very basic and not professional way:

```
Sub DisplayLoop()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

RestartX:
    wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

    wkb.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

    wkb.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

    ' if you have following two lines macro will stop at sheet1 x2 time
    wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
GoTo RestartX

End Sub
```

This will work however stopping it may be a problem :). To be able to stop this is Ctrl+Pause (Hopefully :) )

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this with a DO loop:

```
Do
   Switch to 1
   wait
   Switch to 2
   etc
Loop Until StopCommand = True
```

Then on each sheet, put a button which simply sets StopCommand as True.  You'll have to declare that Boolean variable so that everything can see it (and set it to False before you start the loop), and while global variables have their downsides, for what you're doing it should work fine.

That in itself would finish the cycle and exit after the last "slide" after you've clicked on a button; you could exit after "this" slide's time by simply enclosing each Activate and Wait statement in

```
If Not StopCommand Then
   Activate... 
   Wait...
End If
```

That way you'd exit after the delay for "this slide" finishes.

Comment: hi, just out of curiosity, will you be able to click that button while the other macro is running?

Comment: is there a way to pause a running macro?